# iTerm2: Saving Global Shortcut Keys

Tags: iterm

In iTerm2, I can define `"Global Shortcut Keys"`, which is great. I can also `"Load Presets"` within this view. But how can I save `"Global Shortcut Keys"`?

I don't see an option to do this anywhere:

[image].

Answer (score 1):

You can save different settings by going to the Profile Tab and creating a new Profile. It will have a tab at the right for setting key settings, and you can select/deselect that profile to enable your customized tabs.

[image]

If you want/need to edit the mappings en-masse, there is a file called `PresetKeyMappings.plist` inside the Resources folder in the app. (Right click on app, choose "Show Package Contents".)

Within the Profiles tab, there is also a pop-up menu at the bottom for bulk copying presets from a given profile. (Selected in the image...)

Comment: Thanks. Once I do that, where can I find my profile in disk to make a backup copy? (in case my computer crashes)